# Putting 2 images side by side

Tags: html, css, web

I have a little bit of a problem here. I have 2 images that i need to put side by side on my timeline, but whatever I do the other one ends up under the first image(Image1). I tried putting `style="float: right;"` on the other image(Image2) but it only moves the second image to the right by a bit.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div style="overflow:auto; padding: 2em; max-width: 1000px; max-height: 500px; background-color: rgb(182,0,0);" class="container">
<div class="timeline">
<div class="timeline-item">
<div class="year">2014<span class="marker"><span class="dot"></span></span></div>
<div class="info"><img src="" style="border-style: none;" class="info" /><br />   
<div style="text-align: center;"> ACTIVITY INFORMATION HERE</div></div></div>
<div class="timeline-item">
<div class="year"><span class="marker"><span class="dot"></span></span></div>
<div class="info"><img src="" style="border-style: none;" class="info" />
<div style="text-align: center;"> ACTIVITY INFORMATION HERE</div></div></div>
<div class="timeline-item">
<div class="year"><span class="marker"><span class="dot"></span></span></div>
<div class="info"><img src="" style="border-style: none;" class="info" />
<div style="text-align: center;"> ACTIVITY INFORMATION HERE</div></div></div>
<div class="timeline-item">
<div class="year"><span class="marker"><span class="dot"></span></span></div>
<div class="info"><img src="" style="border-style: none;" class="info" />
<div style="text-align: center;"> ACTIVITY INFORMATION HERE</div></div></div>
<div class="timeline-item">
<div class="year"><span class="marker"><span class="dot"></span></span></div>
<div class="info"><img src="" style="border-style: none;" class="info" />
<div style="text-align: center;"> ACTIVITY INFORMATION HERE</div></div></div>
<div class="timeline-item">
<div class="year">2013<span class="marker"><span class="dot"></span></span></div>
<div class="info"><img align="right" width="213" height="213" class="info" src="/Clients/019.jpg" style="border-style: none;" alt="Image1" />
<img align="right" width="213" height="213" class="info" alt="Image2" src="/Clients/281.jpg" style="border-style: none;" /><br />
<div style="text-align: center;">January 26 to 27 - Seminar &amp; Team Building @ SN David Apartelle</div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Here's my CSS code:

```
    <style>
    div {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .timeline {
        width: 400px;
    }
    .timeline .timeline-item {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .timeline .timeline-item .info, .timeline .timeline-item .year {
        color: #E87474;
        display: block;
        float:left;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
        transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    .timeline .timeline-item.close .info, .timeline .timeline-item.close .year {
        color: #ccc;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
        transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    .timeline .timeline-item .year {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 22%;
    }
    .timeline .timeline-item .info {
        width: 500px;
        width: 78%;
        margin-left: -2px;
        padding: 5px 0 40px 35px;
        border-left: 4px solid #FFE400;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 20px;
    }
    .timeline .timeline-item .marker {
        background-color: #eee;
        border: 4px solid #FFE400;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        border-radius: 100px;
        display: block;
        float: right;
        margin-right: -14px;
        z-index: 2000;
        position: relative;
    }
    .timeline .timeline-item.active .info, .timeline .timeline-item:hover .info {
        color: #ffffff;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
        transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    .timeline .timeline-item.active .year, .timeline .timeline-item:hover .year {
        color: #FFE400;
    }
    .timeline .timeline-item .marker .dot {
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
        transition: all 1s ease;
        display: block;
        border: 4px solid white;
        height: 12px;
        width: 12px;
        border-radius: 100px;
        float: right;
        z-index: 2000;
        position: relative;
    }
    .timeline .timeline-item.active .marker .dot, .timeline .timeline-item:hover .marker .dot {
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
        transition: all 1s ease;
        background-color: #0F8DC7;
        box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    .info{
        transition: all 1s ease;
        opacity: 0.2;
        filter: alpha(opacity=20);
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .info:hover{
        transition: all 1s ease;
        position: relative;
        opacity: 1.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    }
</style>
```

Where did I go wrong with this?
Hope to hear some answers ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: The images look side-by-side to me: http://jsfiddle.net/8q0ystup/. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run your code and it shows side-by-side. I think its on your class that you defined. Try to check your css if you set the width on the divs then adjust the size and run your program again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your container isnt wide enough. Make sure the parent element(s) are at least 426px wide.

Also id suggest floating both your images left and adding a clearfix after them.

```
<div class="timeline-item">
<div class="year">2013<span class="marker"><span class="dot"></span></span></div>
<div class="info">
<img style="float:left;" width="213" height="213" alt="" class="info" style="border-style: none;" src="019.jpg" />
<img style="float:left;" width="213" height="213" class="info" style="border-style: none;" src="281.jpg" alt="" />
<div style="clear:both;" style="text-align: center;">CAPTION HERE</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The container i have is set at max-width: 1000px;

Answer (score 0):

You gave your

```
.timeline {width: 400px;} 
.info {width:500px;width:78%}
```

then you are making images with width of 218px and adding them class .info,. which has width of 500px and 78% !, where 78% is gonna be applied.

How its gonna stay inside that parent container ? I created a fiddle. and gave your timeline class a border of 1px, to show the size of parent container.

Comment me what i'm missing here, then may help you.

[JS Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/happy2deepak/6o32g1w1/1/)

Comment: actually, you sir hit that point on the head. How can I fix that?

Comment: depends, what the size of of those time you want? you reduce the image size,less than 50% of main parent container.

secondly, remove that info class from img tag. and give another class, give property of 
max-width:100%;height:auto;display:inline-block; 
or use a wrapper to put each inside it, give it float:left or you can also work that image part with display:table-cell property.

Comment: i included the info class within the img tag so that i could have a simultaneous hover effect on both the images and the timeline itself.

the images right now are at 213x213.

Comment: simple. give that transitions in another class, and use that class for effects on images or where you want.
example: 
.delay {transition:all 0.2s ease}
.time-img {max-width:100%;height:auto;}

<img class="delay time-img" src="someimg-1.jpg" alt="">
<img class="delay time-img" src="someimg-2.jpg" alt="">


it will work

Comment: isn't that double classes within the img tag? "delay" and "time-img"?

Comment: yes, so what?

multiple classes is never an issue in css or HTML, its the best way..! saves size, redundancy, easy to handle different properties.